# Marshal char* to c# string after sent over network

Tags: c#, c, networking, marshalling

I am building a client application in C# that is communicating with a Server that is written in C. Everything works fine until I try to send a char* over the network and convert it to a C# string.

Here is how sending and receiving works.
I use a struct to send all of the data. It looks something like this:

```
struct NetworkRequest {
    int value;
    char *testCharPointer;
};
```

This struct is then converted to a char* and sent over the network

```
char *buffer = (char *) (void *)request;
```

On the C# side I receive this data and convert it back to a struct with the following code:

```
static NetworkRequest convertToRequest(byte[] arr)
{
    NetworkRequest str = new NetworkRequest();

    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(str);
    IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
    try
    {
        ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

        Marshal.Copy(arr, 0, ptr, size);

        str = (NetworkRequest)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, str.GetType());
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    }

    return str;
}
```

This works completely fine for all datatypes except char* and strings.

When I receive a string and print it to the console in C# I get weird results as shown in the following example:
Char* sent from C: 'hello'
String received in C#: 'QÈüìt'

**What I have already tried:**
I have tried Marshaling the C# string as shown

```
struct NetworkRequest
{
    public int value;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 100)] public string testString;
};
```

I remove the [MarshalAs] I get a System.AccessViolationException.

**Edit:**
Thanks to everyone in the comments of this post for helping me find the answer :). My problem was that I was sending the address of the char, not the actual string. All I had to do to fix the problem was the replace the char* in the struct with a char[].

Comment: It seems like your C code isn't actually sending the string. Only the address of the string. Because the struct only contains the address of the string, not the actual string. Is that right?

Comment: ensure your sending side really sends the bytes contained in the struct member, not an address. In the receiving end, you could use BitConverter.ToString to read the string after reading the integer.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran the bytes contained in the struct member are the address

Comment: @user253751 , but sending an mem address over network doesn't make sense. It needs to be dereferenced and the string must be sent over the wire.

Comment: @arandomperson , you can refer to this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshalling-classes-structures-and-unions#structures-sample) to handle struct marshalling in C#,

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The C program needs to make sure it actually sends the string and not just the memory address of the string.

Comment: The C code needs to declare it `char[100] testCharPointer`

Comment: Thank you for your answers, it works correctly now by changing from char* to char[].